# how can we remove unwanted values in output content?

Tags: python, csv

whenever am reading my csv file am getting an output like this

```
['At Home', '0.0023042115']
['Family', '0.0001275907']
['Time', '0.0005935242']
['Work', '0.0012768792']
['Past Actions', '0.0001357854']
['Games', '0.0032438747']
['Internet', '0.0008639338']
['Location', '0.0001233796']
['Fun', '0.0035238147']
['Food/Clothes', '0.0080727641']
['Poetic', '4.691183298570359e+AC0-06']
['Books/Movies', '2.1300704813858456e+AC0-06']
['Religion', '0']
['Romance', '0.0005935134']
['Swearing', '3.217031124518803e+AC0-05']
['Politics', '0.0075492962']
['Music', '7.224535286344926e+AC0-05']
['School', '2.0853873920424672e+AC0-06']
['Business', '0.0056130667']
['end+AF8-with+AF8-able', '0.001345825']
['end+AF8-with+AF8-al', '0.0024110161']
['end+AF8-with+AF8-ful', '0.0013767934']
['end+AF8-with+AF8-ible', '0.0022098726']
['end+AF8-with+AF8-ic', '0.0023514306']
['end+AF8-with+AF8-ive', '0.0037701555']
['end+AF8-with+AF8-less', '0.0010593697']
['end+AF8AXw-with+AF8-ly', '7.89403499813603e+AC0-05']
['end+AF8-with+AF8-ous', '9.940547915993254e+AC0-05']
['sorry+AF8-word', '5.662225052323463e+AC0-05']
['Starting+AF8-with+AF8-Apolog', '0.0003042999']
['Help+ACE-', '0.0003773039']
['I understand', '0.0001320813']
['+ACI-Attention', ' please+ACE-+ACI-', '0']
['+ACI-Ok', ' I see+ACI-', '0']
['Damn+ACE-', '0']
['How sweet+ACE-', '2.0201595541210387e+AC0-06']
["That's too bad", '0']
['Come on+ACE-', '0.0014614134']
['Whatever', '0']
["That's bad", '0']
["It's cold", '0']
["That's dumb", '0']
['Help+ACE-', '0.0003773039']
['Oh no+ACE-', '0']
['What?', '0']
['Is that right?', '0']
['Disgusting', '0.0001809821']
['This is hopeless', '0']
['Really?', '0.0004255353']
["I'm angry", '0']
['I wonder', '0']
["I don't like this", '0']
['Really?', '0.0004255353']
["Let's celebrate+ACE-", '0']
['Disgusting', '0.0001809821']
["I don't know", '0']
['Yes', '0']
['Lovely', '0.0001642891']
["I'm so evil+ACE-", '0']
['No', '0.0005265143']
['+ACI-No', " it isn't+ACE-/Did not+ACE-+ACI-", '0']
['I see', '0.0013579047']
['Fancy+ACE-', '0']
['Wonderful+ACE-', '0.0006769606']
["I'm exerting myself", '0']
["I didn't mean to do that", '0']
['That hurts', '0']
['+ACI-Hey', ' you+ACE-+ACI-', '0']
['Oh no...', '0']
['It stinks+ACE-', '0']
["That's nothing", '0']
['That was close+ACE-', '0.0010088511']
['+ACI-Whispering+ACE-Hey', ' you+ACE-+ACI-', '0']
["I can't believe this+ACE-", '0']
['Be quiet', '0']
['Go away', '0']
['Disappointing', '0']
['Yes', '0']
['Oh no+ACE-', '0']
['No', '0.0005265143']
['+ACI-Wait', " I'm thinking+ACI-", '0']
['This is fun+ACE-', '0.0016848004']
['Unbelievable+ACE-', '0']
['Amazing+ACE-', '0.0005387173']
["Let's celebrate+ACE-", '0']
['Yes+ACE-', '0.0003639123']
['Yes+ACE-', '0.0003639123']
["I'm excited+ACE-", '0']
['Hey you+ACE-', '0']
['+ACI-Yes', ' it is+ACE- Or Did so+ACE-+ACI-', '0']
['Disgusting+ACE-', '0']
['+ACI-Haha', ' well said+ACE-+ACI-', '0']
["+ACI-+AFs-'CD'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003041055']
["+ACI-+AFs-'DT'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003041055']
["+ACI-+AFs-'EX'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0002694121']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJ'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003041055']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJR'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003427676']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJS'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0029483492']
["+ACI-+AFs-'NN'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0001060578']
["+ACI-+AFs-'RBR'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0002081336']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBD'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0001925713']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBG'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '9.068096527379936e+AC0-06']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBN'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0011585203']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBP'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.000277034']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBZ'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0009891459']
["+ACI-+AFs-'WDT'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0015045239']
["+ACI-+AFs-'WP'", " 'CC'", " 'CD'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0013222853']
["+ACI-+AFs-'CD'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0002694121']
["+ACI-+AFs-'DT'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003605792']
["+ACI-+AFs-'EX'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003605792']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJ'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003605792']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJR'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003623141']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJS'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0028113198']
["+ACI-+AFs-'NN'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0002380414']
["+ACI-+AFs-'RBR'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0002524272']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBD'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0002694121']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBG'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '6.8763849316489e+AC0-07']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBN'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0013536177']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBP'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.000228122']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBZ'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0011060342']
["+ACI-+AFs-'WDT'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0018250935']
["+ACI-+AFs-'WP'", " 'CD'", " 'DT'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0013798266']
["+ACI-+AFs-'CD'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0005956604']
["+ACI-+AFs-'DT'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.000739265']
["+ACI-+AFs-'EX'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0005909166']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJ'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0005909166']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJR'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.000548832']
["+ACI-+AFs-'NN'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0007274935']
["+ACI-+AFs-'RBR'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0006394694']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBD'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003994929']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBG'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.000165679']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBN'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0007330517']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBP'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0003164934']
["+ACI-+AFs-'VBZ'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0006952293']
["+ACI-+AFs-'WDT'", " 'DT'", " 'EX'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0009373422']
["+ACI-+AFs-'CD'", " 'IN'", " 'JJ'+AF0-+ACI-", '2.3855039963693414e+AC0-05']
["+ACI-+AFs-'DT'", " 'IN'", " 'JJ'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0004035301']
["+ACI-+AFs-'EX'", " 'IN'", " 'JJ'+AF0-+ACI-", '3.612301342137506e+AC0-05']
["+ACI-+AFs-'JJ'", " 'IN'", " 'JJ'+AF0-+ACI-", '0.0001610457']
```

mycode is as below:

```
with open("Dataset/MALE_Training/MI_score_Male.csv","r")as finp :           
    fv_raeder = csv.reader(finp)
    heading = fv_raeder.next()                             
    for row in fv_raeder :
        print row
```

what is this `+ACI-+AFs`, `'EX'+AF0-+ACI` etc are mean? how can I remove this? Can you suggest some solution for my problem?

csv file contains:

```
 Conversation   0.0010855412
    At Home 0.0023042115
    Family  0.0001275907
    Time    0.0005935242
    Work    0.0012768792
    Past Actions    0.0001357854
    Games   0.0032438747
    Internet    0.0008639338
    Location    0.0001233796
    Fun 0.0035238147
    Food/Clothes    0.0080727641
    Poetic  4.691183298570359e-06
    Books/Movies    2.1300704813858456e-06
    Religion    0
    Romance 0.0005935134
    Swearing    3.217031124518803e-05
    Politics    0.0075492962
    Music   7.224535286344926e-05
    School  2.0853873920424672e-06
    Business    0.0056130667
    end_with_able   0.001345825
    end_with_al 0.0024110161
    end_with_ful    0.0013767934
    end_with_ible   0.0022098726
    end_with_ic 0.0023514306
    end_with_ive    0.0037701555
    end_with_less   0.0010593697
    end__with_ly    7.89403499813603e-05
    end_with_ous    9.940547915993254e-05
    sorry_word  5.662225052323463e-05
    Starting_with_Apolog    0.0003042999
    Help!   0.0003773039
    I understand    0.0001320813
    Attention, please!  0
    Ok, I see   0
    Damn!   0
    How sweet!  2.0201595541210387e-06
    That's too bad  0
    Come on!    0.0014614134
    Whatever    0
    That's bad  0
    It's cold   0
    That's dumb 0
    Help!   0.0003773039
    Oh no!  0
    What?   0
    Is that right?  0
    Disgusting  0.0001809821
    This is hopeless    0
    Really? 0.0004255353
    I'm angry   0
    I wonder    0
    I don't like this   0
    Really? 0.0004255353
    Let's celebrate!    0
    Disgusting  0.0001809821
    I don't know    0
    Yes 0
    Lovely  0.0001642891
    I'm so evil!    0
    No  0.0005265143
    No, it isn't!/Did not!  0
    I see   0.0013579047
    Fancy!  0
    Wonderful!  0.0006769606
    I'm exerting myself 0
    I didn't mean to do that    0
    That hurts  0
    Hey, you!   0
    Oh no...    0
    It stinks!  0
    That's nothing  0
    That was close! 0.0010088511
    Whispering!Hey, you!    0
    I can't believe this!   0
    Be quiet    0
    Go away 0
    Disappointing   0
    Yes 0
    Oh no!  0
    No  0.0005265143
    Wait, I'm thinking  0
    This is fun!    0.0016848004
    Unbelievable!   0
    Amazing!    0.0005387173
    Let's celebrate!    0
    Yes!    0.0003639123
    Yes!    0.0003639123
    I'm excited!    0
    Hey you!    0
    Yes, it is! Or Did so!  0
    Disgusting! 0
    Haha, well said!    0
    ['CD', 'CC', 'CD']  0.0003041055
    ['DT', 'CC', 'CD']  0.0003041055
    ['EX', 'CC', 'CD']  0.0002694121
    ['JJ', 'CC', 'CD']  0.0003041055
    ['JJR', 'CC', 'CD'] 0.0003427676
    ['JJS', 'CC', 'CD'] 0.0029483492
    ['NN', 'CC', 'CD']  0.0001060578
    ['RBR', 'CC', 'CD'] 0.0002081336
    ['VBD', 'CC', 'CD'] 0.0001925713
    ['VBG', 'CC', 'CD'] 9.068096527379936e-06
    ['VBN', 'CC', 'CD'] 0.0011585203
    ['VBP', 'CC', 'CD'] 0.000277034
    ['VBZ', 'CC', 'CD'] 0.0009891459
    ['WDT', 'CC', 'CD'] 0.0015045239
    ['WP', 'CC', 'CD']  0.0013222853
    ['CD', 'CD', 'DT']  0.0002694121
    ['DT', 'CD', 'DT']  0.0003605792
    ['EX', 'CD', 'DT']  0.0003605792
    ['JJ', 'CD', 'DT']  0.0003605792
    ['JJR', 'CD', 'DT'] 0.0003623141
    ['JJS', 'CD', 'DT'] 0.0028113198
    ['NN', 'CD', 'DT']  0.0002380414
    ['RBR', 'CD', 'DT'] 0.0002524272
    ['VBD', 'CD', 'DT'] 0.0002694121
    ['VBG', 'CD', 'DT'] 6.8763849316489e-07
    ['VBN', 'CD', 'DT'] 0.0013536177
    ['VBP', 'CD', 'DT'] 0.000228122
    ['VBZ', 'CD', 'DT'] 0.0011060342
    ['WDT', 'CD', 'DT'] 0.0018250935
    ['WP', 'CD', 'DT']  0.0013798266
    ['CD', 'DT', 'EX']  0.0005956604
    ['DT', 'DT', 'EX']  0.000739265
    ['EX', 'DT', 'EX']  0.0005909166
    ['JJ', 'DT', 'EX']  0.0005909166
    ['JJR', 'DT', 'EX'] 0.000548832
    ['NN', 'DT', 'EX']  0.0007274935
    ['RBR', 'DT', 'EX'] 0.0006394694
    ['VBD', 'DT', 'EX'] 0.0003994929
    ['VBG', 'DT', 'EX'] 0.000165679
    ['VBN', 'DT', 'EX'] 0.0007330517
    ['VBP', 'DT', 'EX'] 0.0003164934
    ['VBZ', 'DT', 'EX'] 0.0006952293
    ['WDT', 'DT', 'EX'] 0.0009373422
    ['CD', 'IN', 'JJ']  2.3855039963693414e-05
    ['DT', 'IN', 'JJ']  0.0004035301
    ['EX', 'IN', 'JJ']  3.612301342137506e-05
    ['JJ', 'IN', 'JJ']  0.0001610457
    ['JJR', 'IN', 'JJ'] 0.0001610457
    ['JJS', 'IN', 'JJ'] 0.0033707076
    ['NN', 'IN', 'JJ']  0.0007419509
    ['RBR', 'IN', 'JJ'] 7.329654519463405e-08
    ['VBD', 'IN', 'JJ'] 5.950344732515763e-05
    ['VBG', 'IN', 'JJ'] 0.0007109534
    ['VBN', 'IN', 'JJ'] 0.0006920679
    ['VBP', 'IN', 'JJ'] 3.6209960493105995e-05
    ['VBZ', 'IN', 'JJ'] 0.0018789858
    ['WDT', 'IN', 'JJ'] 0.0037640204
    ['WP', 'IN', 'JJ']  0.0011824782
    ['CD', 'JJ', 'JJR'] 0.003625445
    ['DT', 'JJ', 'JJR'] 0.0028113198

    ['VB', 'WDT']   0.0013284551
    ['VBD', 'WDT']  0.0005987498
    ['VBG', 'WDT']  0.0017245536
    ['VBN', 'WDT']  0.0008969116
    ['VBP', 'WDT']  0.0016863023
    ['VBZ', 'WDT']  0.0020814437
    CC  5.111969137490955e-05
    CD  0.0004017943
    DT  0
    EX  0.0005909166
    IN  0
    JJ  0.0001610457
    JJR 0.003469816
    JJS 0.0010446082
    CC  5.111969137490955e-05
    CD  0.0004017943
    DT  0
    EX  0.0005909166
    IN  0
    JJ  0.0001610457
    JJR 0.003469816
    JJS 0.0010446082
    MD  0.0006791731
    NN  0
    NNS 5.149809586568776e-05
    PRP 0.0014294222
    RB  0.0004972152
    RBR 0.0007214601
    RP  0.0001474277
    TO  1.8888999939422496e-05
    VB  3.6038046948563265e-05
    VBD 0.0011007132
    VBG 0.0006148222
    VBN 2.3115793700478806e-07
    VBP 0.0016502422
    VBZ 0.0032336121
    WDT 0.0011788791
    WP  3.35853998744088e-05
    WRB 2.4547859289217235e-05
```

Comment: All the data in your lists comes from the CSV file, unless you have additional code you didn't share with us.

Comment: yes all the data is read from the same CSV

Comment: Looks like [UTF-7](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7). Probably done quite on purpose.

Comment: yes i have added #-*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the top my file..

Comment: You're muddling source encoding (`#-- coding: utf-8 --`) with data encoding - while your python code may be UTF-8, the file you're reading is UTF-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tripleee mentioned, that's UTF-7 encoding. By using [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open), you can decode it in the background:

```
from codecs import open

with open("Dataset/MALE_Training/MI_score_Male.csv", encoding='utf-7') as finp:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(finp)
    heading = next(csv_reader)                             
    for row in csv_reader:
        print row
```